# @InjectMocks, object instanciated in @Test but null in @ParameterizedTest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to unit test a class using mockito (version 5.3.1) and junit (4.13.2).
The test class is annotated `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, the tested object is

```
    @InjectMocks
    TestedBean testedBean;
```

and all its dependencies are annotated with `@Mock`. This approach works correctly already for a few test methods which are all annotated with `@Test`. 
Now consider these two test methods:

```
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        String value = "value";
        String filter = "val";
        boolean expectedResult = true;

        // when
        var result = testedBean.testedMethod(value, filter, null);

        // then
        assertThat(result, is(expectedResult));
    }


    @CsvSource({
            "value, val, true"
    })
    @ParameterizedTest
    public void test2(String value, String filter, boolean expectedResult) {

        // when
        var result = testedBean.testedMethod(value, filter, null);

        // then
        assertThat(result, is(expectedResult));
    }
```

The `@Test` annotated test passes correctly while the `@ParameterizedTest` throws a `NullPointerException` as `this.testedBean` is `null`. 
How is it possible that the object is constructed as expected in a `@Test` but not in a `@ParameterizedTest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` doesn't support parameterized tests. The test class has to be annotated additionally with

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

to make it work.